# MySQL on AWS RDS facing SEARCH BY STRING performance issues

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a development database and a production one. Both the database servers, hosted on AWS RDS (MySQL environment), were working fine till the production one has encountered major speed issues with SELECT statements for strings (using either = and LIKE). The size of the table (on production) I am searching from is about 100k rows but it can take 1min + to do a simple string search on phpmyadmin. The development db table is about 30k rows and results are returned in less than 0.1s.

Is this an AWS issue? Or some MySQL config problem. Note that this has only started occurring recently.

Extra: After I do a string search on the table, my read/write latency and queue depth shoots up. The only way I can resolve it is by making a snapshot of the server (reboot does not help).

Comment: What sort of searches (specific queries)? What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` show is going on? What does `EXPLAIN` show? Are your columns properly indexed?

Comment: Example: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE COLUMN = 'some simple string'; where COLUMN is varchar(100). SHOW PROCESSLIST shows that SEARCH query taking very long. After killing it, the read/write latency is improved but not back to before running the query itself. Search by ID (which is an indexed column) has no performance lag. Its the columns holding STRING values being affected.

Comment: Is the column indexed? You mention `LIKE` queries - are they wildcarded?

Comment: Please add table DDL's for both environments and sample queries in OP.

Comment: the column is not indexed (even though it isnt, unlikely that the problem happens all of a sudden?). no wildcards on query.

production table DDL: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9a9775f7377caaf35064/
development DDL: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9f3ca6c52fb31d66e478.
Query: SELECT * FROM `attendee_profile` WHERE COMPANYNAME LIKE 'TESTABC'

Comment: Search by ID (for example, SELECT * FROM attendee_profile WHERE ID_ATTENDEE_LOGIN = 102452;) performance is normal (fast as expected)

Comment: What size instances are you using for both environments? If you were to do an explain, your query is hitting the disk for some reason. Company name is also not indexed, its probably doing a full table scan for matches.

Comment: Development RDS: Magnetic 5GB, mysql 5.6.21b, db.t1.micro, no mutli-az, IOPS disabled.
Production RDS: General purpose SSD 8GB, mysql 5.6.21, db.t2.micro, no mutli-az, IOPS disabled.
Tried changing production to Magnetic disk, 12GB, 5.6.21b and 5.6.22 also but with no change.
Production db size is about 900MB

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT...` for each item you are asking about.  Also, state how big the table is, plus the output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%buffer%".  _Either_ you need better indexes _or_ you need a bigger RDS instance; you have not provided sufficient info do distinguish.